# How to show Different data in UI then Backend Data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to angular. From Backend i am getting space data as attached in console image.
[image]

```
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mt-3 pr-0 overflow-auto d-flex align-items-center">
    <div *ngFor="let data of spaces; let i=index;" class="spaceTabs cursorPointer"
      [ngClass]="{ active: selectedSpace === data.space }">
      <p class="rangeTag">Rs: {{data.range}}</p>
      <span (click)="spaceTabHandler(data)">{{data.space | titlecase}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is how i am showing space data as data.space in UI.
My requirement is livingroom should display as Living, diningroom as Dining Room .
How can i manipulate data in UI according to requirement.

Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: I take it you don't have access to just add another field to be returned from your API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pipe to transform your output

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'space'
})
export class SpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value:string, args?:string): any {
        switch(value || null) {
            case 'livingroom':
                return 'Living';
            case 'diningroom':
                return 'Dining Room';
            default:
                return value;
        }
     }
  }
```

`<span (click)="spaceTabHandler(data)">{{data.space | titlecase | space}}</span>`

Answer (score 0):

you can create a pipe, then use that pipe to show what you want,

like below

```
import {Pipe} from ‘angular2/core’;

@Pipe({
  name: ‘unCamelCase’
})

export class UnCamelCasePipe {
  transform(value: string) {

     return value
        // insert a space between lower & upper
        .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1 $2')
        // space before last upper in a sequence followed by lower
        .replace(/\b([A-Z]+)([A-Z])([a-z])/, '$1 $2$3')
        // uppercase the first character
        .replace(/^./,(str) => str.toUpperCase())
   }
}
```

then use it like

```
 <span (click)="spaceTabHandler(data)">{{data.space | unCamelCase}}</span>
```

make sure you add `UnCamelCasePipe` to your module providers

Answer (score 0):

Create a viewModel with the fields u need in the front end. Then after the backend call returns populate your data where u set Living Room instead of livingroom. That is usually the correct approach

SO in typescript:

```
export class DataViewModel{
    public SpaceName:string;
    public .... other properties you need 
}
```

Then in your angular component in the subscribe to the back end call:

```
this.mybackendmethod.get().subscribe((backenddata)=>{
const viewModel = new Array<DataViewModel>();
   backenddata.foreach((item)=>{
   const viewModelItem = new DataViewModel();
   switch(item.space){
    case 'livingroom':
     viewModelItem.SpaceName= 'Living Room';
      break;

}
viewModel.push(viewModelItem);
});
});
```

Something like this.

Comment: I did not get your answer. Can u Please provide some example or be more specific.

Comment: pretty simple, create a class in typescript to represent your view (viewmodel). When u get your data from the backend. Loop through it and create the viewmodel, WHen looping do a check on livingroom, blah and convert it to the text you need

Comment: Thanks fir detailed answer. I will try it.